# Xcode 7 - How to initiate interface recording for UI Testing?

Tags: xctest, ios9, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I'm looking at the WWDC 2015 session 104 "What's new in Xcode" and see that in Xcode 7 I can record interface unit tests to automate clicking on buttons, enter text, etc.

I have a new project created with UITests included, but **how do I actually start recording interface interactions for UITests?**

Here's the snippet included in the test:

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
    self.continueAfterFailure = NO;
    // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
    [[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The record button is the red button in the bottom left corner of your main text editor.
The button will be greyed out when you are not in a method that you can record into.

[image: Xcode UI test record button]